# Correct way to do a MVC UML Diagram

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, uml

tried researching this before asking but there is that many versions id like to get a definitive way to do an ASP.NET MVC UML Diagram, i attempted one below but i want to make sure im doing it correctly

also i see some articles state that the model updates the view and not the controller? im wondering is this true since i have my views using the Ienumerable model for displaying model data.

here is the mockup

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use a general class `<<controller>>` from which the controllers inherit get/set. Probably a generic class would be nice to construct the id based on the class name. You should further stereotype your M and V classes accordingly.

Your design lacks any association between M, V and C. You should associate V -> C -> M (directed association). Means: a view has a controller. A controller has a model.

Just notice that you use plural for V classes. Better use singular. There my be many instances but only one class.

Re your question about model updating a view: e.g. Ruby has scaffolding which bypassed the controller in some cases so the model directly punches through to the view.

Comment: Thanks Thomas! Appreciate it! :)